# Single insertion of data on one date in SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[K_FS_InsertMrpDetails]
@date datetime,
@feedtype varchar(50),
@rateperkg float,
@rateper50kg float,
@updatedby varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO K_FS_FeedMrpDetails([date], feedtype, rateperkg, rateper50kg, updatedby, updatedon)
   VALUES(@date, @feedtype, @rateperkg, @rateper50kg, @updatedby, getdate())

   SELECT '1' AS status
END
```

With this query we insert 9 rows at a time but what I want is in one same date do not insert again different details. How can I please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [unique constraint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx) on the column `[date]`. That will prevent you from adding more than one row with the same `[date]` value.

**Update:**

To allow 9 rows for each date you can add a computed column `D` that removes the time part and you need to add a column that will hold the values 1 to 9 `R`. Use a check constraint on `R` to only allow 1-9. Finally you create a unique constraint on (R, D).

Sample table definition:

```
create table T
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  DT datetime not null,
  R tinyint check (R in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)) not null,
  D as dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, DT), 0),
  constraint ux_RD unique (R,D)
)
```

Try with this:

```
insert into T(DT, R) values(getdate(), 1)
insert into T(DT, R) values(getdate(), 2)
insert into T(DT, R) values(getdate(), 1)
```

First and second insert works fine, the third raises a unique constraint exception.

Comment: @santhosha How is not working? Are you still allowed to add duplicate rows even if you have a unique constraint?

Comment: Yah.. It is allowing duplicate values

Comment: @santhosha Ok, so you have a `datetime` value with different times but want to prevent duplicates on the date part (remove time) from that value?

Comment: Actually for the first time it will take 9 rows with same date  after that i don't want to insert with that same date of different data How can I?

Comment: So you want to allow up to 9 rows with the same date?